# How to insert nested array of a multidimensional array into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional aray that i want to insert into mysql database. Everything works fine but iwant a better solution as the rows repeat itself following the nested array

here is my json

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 48728,
            "name": "MOVIES AT THE PARK @ GIBA GORGE",
            "url": "Some URL",
            "imageUrl": "Some Path",
            "dateCreated": "2018-06-08T09:18:59.717",
            "lastModified": "2018-06-26T14:20:45.0214921",
            "startDate": "2018-07-28T17:00:00",
            "endDate": "2018-07-28T22:00:00",
            "venue": {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "Giba Gorge Mountain Bike Park",
                "addressLine1": "110 Stockville Road",
                "addressLine2": "",
                "latitude": -29.8276051,
                "longitude": 30.781735700000013
            },
            "locality": {
                "levelOne": "South Africa",
                "levelTwo": "KwaZulu-Natal",
                "levelThree": "Clifton Canyon"
            },
            "organiser": {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "Ultra Glow SA ",
                "phone": "0822603351",
                "mobile": "0828927837",
                "facebookUrl": "",
                "twitterHandle": "",
                "hashTag": "UGMOVIES",
                "organiserPageUrl": "some url"
            },
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Film & Media"
                },
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "Food & Drink"
                }
            ],
            "tickets": [
                {
                    "id": 98655,
                    "name": "ADULT TICKET",
                    "soldOut": false,
                    "provisionallySoldOut": false,
                    "price": 100,
                    "salesStart": "2018-06-26T11:52:00",
                    "salesEnd": "2018-07-28T17:00:00",
                    "description": "",
                    "donation": false,
                    "vendorTicket": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 98656,
                    "name": "UNDER 12",
                    "soldOut": false,
                    "provisionallySoldOut": false,
                    "price": 80,
                    "salesStart": "2018-06-26T11:53:00",
                    "salesEnd": "2018-07-28T17:00:00",
                    "description": "",
                    "donation": false,
                    "vendorTicket": false
                }
            ],
            "schedules": [
            ],
            "refundFeePayableBy": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 51681,
            "name": "ULTRA GLOW COLOUR CRUZ @ RIETVLEI ZOO FARM",
            "url": "some url",
            "imageUrl": "some path",
            "dateCreated": "2018-06-26T12:12:07.3",
            "lastModified": "2018-06-28T15:22:24.1579751",
            "startDate": "2018-08-12T10:00:00",
            "endDate": "2018-08-12T14:00:00",
            "venue": {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "Rietvlei Zoo Farm",
                "addressLine1": "101 Swartkoppies Road",
                "addressLine2": "",
                "latitude": -26.3117147,
                "longitude": 28.07989120000002
            },
            "locality": {
                "levelOne": "South Africa",
                "levelTwo": "Gauteng",
                "levelThree": "Johannesburg South"
            },
            "organiser": {
                "id": 0,
                "name": " Ultra Glow South Africa",
                "phone": "0822603351",
                "mobile": "0828927837",
                "facebookUrl": "",
                "twitterHandle": "",
                "hashTag": "",
                "organiserPageUrl": "some url"
            },
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 60,
                    "name": "Trail Running"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Sports & Fitness"
                }
            ],
            "tickets": [
                {
                    "id": 98735,
                    "name": "ADULT EARLY BIRD",
                    "soldOut": false,
                    "provisionallySoldOut": false,
                    "price": 150,
                    "salesStart": "2018-06-26T12:47:00",
                    "salesEnd": "2018-08-12T10:00:00",
                    "description": "",
                    "donation": false,
                    "vendorTicket": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 98736,
                    "name": "UNDER 12 - EARLY BIRD",
                    "soldOut": false,
                    "provisionallySoldOut": false,
                    "price": 120,
                    "salesStart": "2018-06-26T12:47:00",
                    "salesEnd": "2018-08-12T10:00:00",
                    "description": "",
                    "donation": false,
                    "vendorTicket": false
                }
            ],
            "schedules": [
            ],
            "refundFeePayableBy": 0
        }
    ],
    "pageSize": 10,
    "pages": 1,
    "records": 2,
    "extras": null,
    "message": null,
    "statusCode": 0
}
```

i have tried the following code to insert the relevant datas into database

```
<?php
$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","result");
$jsondata=file_get_contents("result.json");
$json= json_decode($jsondata,true);
$results=$json['results'];
$n= sizeof($results);
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){

$row=$results[$i];
foreach($row['tickets'] as $key => $value){


 $sql="INSERT into 
 event(name,url,imageUrl,dateCreated,eventName,addressLine1,addressLine2,ticketNa me,price) 
 VALUES('".$row["name"]."','".$row["url"]."','".$row["imageUrl"]."','".$row["dateCreated"]."','".$row["venue"]["name"]."','".$row["venue"]["addressLine1"]."','".$row["venue"]["addressLine2"]."','".$value["name"]."','".$value["price"]."')";

    mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    }
}

echo "events data inserted";
?>
```

This enters the respective datas into my database but because of the nested array `tickets` with respective keys `name` and `price` the same events are being posted twice into my database like `MOVIES AT THE PARK @ GIBA GORGE` for price `100` is one one row and `MOVIES AT THE PARK @ GIBA GORGE` for price `80` on another row ... I have to display these datas in future as part of one event name with their the ticket type and price as a table... do you have any idea on any other way i can make it better, instead of having two rows for same events?

Thanks in advance

for those who have been suggesting me not to use for and foreach loop this is my update code after removing for loop and a single foreach loop and it gives me an error of undefined index of name and price under tickets

```
<?php
$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","result");
$jsondata=file_get_contents("result.json");
$json= json_decode($jsondata,true);
$results=$json['results'];

foreach($results as $key => $result){

    $sql="INSERT into `event(name,url,imageUrl,dateCreated,eventName,addressLine1,addressLine2,ticketName,price) VALUES('".$result["name"]."','".$result["url"]."','".$result["imageUrl"]."','".$result["dateCreated"]."','".$result["venue"]["name"]."','".$result["venue"]["addressLine1"]."','".$result["venue"]["addressLine2"]."','".$result["tickets"]["name"]."','".$result["tickets"]["price"]."')";`
    mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
}

echo "events data inserted";
?>
```

hence i have further updated my code by using two foreach loops, one to ietrate through the top level array "results" and the other to iterate through the nested array "tickets"

```
<?php
$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","result");
$jsondata=file_get_contents("result.json");
$json= json_decode($jsondata,true);
$results=$json['results'];

foreach($results as $key => $result){
    foreach($result["tickets"] as $k => $v){
    $sql="INSERT into event(name,url,imageUrl,dateCreated,eventName,addressLine1,addressLine2,ticketName,price) VALUES('".$result["name"]."','".$result["url"]."','".$result["imageUrl"]."','".$result["dateCreated"]."','".$result["venue"]["name"]."','".$result["venue"]["addressLine1"]."','".$result["venue"]["addressLine2"]."','".$v["name"]."','".$v["price"]."')";`
    mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    }
}

echo "events data inserted";
?>
```

that iterates through the nested array so there is nothing wrong in my code now the only problem is i am getting 2 events on my table because of two ticket types adult and children in "tickets" array

so as per many suggestions here i need to create two separate tables for events and tickets i would appreciate if anyone can tell me that how do iconnect these two tables to be able to show the information of my events in html with ticket type and price shown in html table tag thanks in advance

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should aim to fix this asap

Comment: I know i am just testing this on mylocal host.. will do all that later

Comment: Have a separate table for tickets.

Comment: okay then how will i connect them with the datas on events table? i want the ticket name and price for each events and display it into a table tag in html

Answer (score 0):

it's because you're using a foreach within a for. You just want a foreach:

```
foreach ($multiArray as $key => $singleArray) {
    //rest of code, replacing $row with $singleArray['key']. E.g. $singleArray['id']
}
```

update after seeing OP update:

so you would do:

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
  foreach ($row['tickets'] as $ticket) {
    //sql
  }
}
```

this should allow you to use `$ticket['key']` in your SQL - though I do suggest switch to PDO prepared statements to protect yourself from SQL injection.

Also as other suggested, separating tickets into its own table would be highly advantageous to you.

Comment: no i need that for loop to iterate through each value of results array.. the reason why i am getting two events of the same name is because of the nested array "tickets" in json as i am using the keys "name" and "price" under the "tickets" array.. i just want a better solution for that

Comment: @PraneetSinghRoopra yeah.. that's why you just use `$singleArray['tickets']` and loop through that - you're twice looping it because you've nested a foreach within a for, so it goes through it `2 x count(tickets)`

Comment: no bro i urge you to go through my json format i need both for loop and foreach loop because of the nested array "tickets" look closely tickets is an array in itself which has 2 indexes that is it has two arrays within it. hence i need for each loop to iterate through that and th top level for loop is to iterate thrugh the top level arrays

Comment: @PraneetSinghRoopra and I urge you to understand my answer, you have an array: let's call it results. You loop through `results`. This means on each iteration you have a `tickets` array associated with that index. This means doing `$results as $key => $result` in a foreach allows you to loop through `$result['tickets']` and manipulate how you see fit..

Comment: if i do that i get errors Undefined index: name and Undefined index: price and no values go under the mysql

Comment: @PraneetSinghRoopra show updated code in question :)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason that is happening is look at the below code :

```
$row=$results[$i];
foreach($row['tickets'] as $key => $value){

    $sql="INSERT into event(name,url,imageUrl,dateCreated,eventName,addressLine1,addressLine2,ticketNa me,price) VALUES('".$row["name"]."','".$row["url"]."','".$row["imageUrl"]."','".$row["dateCreated]."','".$row["venue"]["name"]."','".$row["venue"]["addressLine1"]."','".$row["venue"]["addressLine2"]."','".$value["name"]."','".$value["price"]."')";

    mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
}
```

The `$row` contains your one main entry and `$row['tickets']` contains 2 entries and you are using the $row main contents inside the loop for tickets. That is the reason you are getting 2 entries. The best way to cope this is to use a single foreach loop instead of using a for and a foreach.

EDIT:

Actually I would like to suggest to normalize your table by breaking this into 2 tables, one for storing event information and the other for using the ticket information. See the structure below:

```
event(id,name,url,imageUrl,addressLine1,addressLine2,dateCreated);
event_tickets(id,event_id,ticketName,price,dateCreated);
```

This will help you maintain the information easily. Also you can modify the code to something like this :

```
$sql="INSERT into event(name,url,imageUrl,addressLine1,addressLine,2dateCreated) VALUES ('".$row['name']."','".$row['url']."','".$row['imageUrl']."','".$row['venue']['addressLine1']."','".$row['venue']['addressLine2']."','".date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."');"
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$event_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
```

And then you can use a foreach to insert the ticket information in the event_tickets table.

Hope this helps

Comment: please suggest how do i use a single foreach loop in the above given json format?

Comment: Edited the answer.